# ElasticSearch is skipping the word "no" from query or facet?

Tags: elasticsearch

We're having problem with ElasticSearch skipping the term **"no"** so we came up with a toy dataset for easier troubleshooting.  Below is the toy collection of 6 documents total (shown on the Sense chrome plugin):

[image: All documents]

And below is the query we're having problem with.  We want it to return all 6 documents with the 4 facets for the **"healthy"** field which should be **[no, yes, hell no, probably no]**.
[image: Troubled query]

Instead, only 4 out of 6 documents were returned and the missing ones, **meat** and **egg**, were those having **"healthy"=="no"** (case insensitive).

[image: Incorrect results]

...and instead of 4 facets we only got 3 back (**"no"** is missing).  Also note that **"probably"** was returned instead of **"probably not"**.  Similarly, only **"hell"** was returned instead of **"hell no"**.

[image: Incorrect facets]

We came up with these examples to illustrate the problem and not to offend anyone's dietary choices!  Many thanks in advance!!!

EDIT: We didn't do anything fancy with the mapping (we did in our real system).  It just simply won't work "out of the box".

[image: Default mapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running into stop words.  "no" is a very typical English stop word, which are words deemed to be so common that they are usually not useful for searching, and so they are eliminated during analysis.  ElasticSearch has actually changed their default behavior to use an empty stop word set, for exactly this reason.  Stop words can be helpful, but if you aren't expecting it, it's just confusing.

You can customize the stop word set being used in your analyzer (such as [StandardAnalyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)).

The ElasticSearch folks have a very insteresting article on stop words as well:  ["Stop Stopping Stop Words: a Look at Common Terms Query"](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/stop-stopping-stop-words-a-look-at-common-terms-query/) (to be clear, common terms queries may not suit your needs, but at least the first few sections should help describe the problem a little better).

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer and links lead me to the solution.  I will post the details of the fix to benefit others later (need to leave the office pronto).